# Number of paths under $x=y$ line

Tags: combinatorics

Let $n$ be a positive integer. For each $0\leq k\le 2n$, on the coordinate plane, among all the $2n$-step path moving from point $(0,0)$ to $(n,n)$ with each move being up or to the right, let $f(k)$ be the number of paths such that $k$ out of the $2n$ steps occur below (possibly touching) the $x=y$ line. What is the value of $k$ that maximizes $f(k)$?

An observation is that $f(k)=0$ if $k$ is odd, because it takes an even number of steps from being on the diagonal one time to the next. For $n=2$, it holds that $f(0)=f(2)=f(4)=2$, and all three numbers maximize $f(k)$.

Comment: They are all indeed equal, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number#Third_proof